# ¿como separar el require.config del requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

estoy utilizando requierejs, quisiera saber si puedo separar ambos(requirejs y requiere.config) en diferentes archivos, me pasa que si pongo todo el codigo en el mismo archivo funciona y sino no me muestra nada:

ej:
requiere.config + requierejs (en un mismo archivo)

```js
require.config({

      paths:{
          'jquery':'jquery',
          'index':'index',
          'persona':'persona'   
      },
    shim : {
       jquery : {
        exports : '$'
       },
      index : {
      deps:['jquery'],
      exports : ['luz','camila','lucio','carlos']
    },

    }
});


requirejs(['jquery','persona'],function($,p){

    const luz = new p('Luz', 'Perez' , 20);
    const camila = new p('Camila', 'Gomez' ,21);
    const lucio = new p('Lucio', 'Fernandez', 22);
    const carlos = new p('Carlos', 'Gonzalez', 23);

    console.log(luz);
    console.log(camila);
    console.log(lucio);
    console.log(carlos);


})
```

ej : requiere.config en un archivo

```js
require.config({

      paths:{
          'jquery':'jquery',
          'index':'index',
          'persona':'persona'   
      },
    shim : {
       jquery : {
        exports : '$'
       },
      index : {
      deps:['jquery'],
      exports : ['luz','camila','lucio','carlos']
    },

    }
});
```

ej: y requierejs en otro

```js
requirejs(['jquery','persona'],function($,p){

    const luz = new p('Luz', 'Perez' , 20);
    const camila = new p('Camila', 'Gomez' ,21);
    const lucio = new p('Lucio', 'Fernandez', 22);
    const carlos = new p('Carlos', 'Gonzalez', 23);

    console.log(luz);
    console.log(camila);
    console.log(lucio);
    console.log(carlos);


})
```

Comment: Vemos el mismo resultado al ejecutar la máquina, quizá sería mejor que pusieras una imagen con el error? O el error directamente?

Comment: hola, es que directamente no muestra nada por consola y si pongo el código donde creo los objetos donde esta el requiere.config si me muestra las personas creadas